# Does an increase in Tax Exemptions mean I will pay less in Tax for each paycheck? (USA)

Tags: united-states, tax-law

I get too big of a refund each year, so I want to get that closer to 0. Not owing and not getting a refund, in tax.

Should I increase "exemptions"?

Also is "Allowance" and "Witholdings" and "Exemptions" all mean the same thing?